# Create a List of characters from string, using only String Functions and not Regular Expressions

Tags: python

Input:

```
data = "~ddd , eee~, ~aaaa~"
```

Desired Output:

```
data = ["~ddd eee~","~aaaa~"]
```

1. Print a list of strings from data, that start and end with "~".
2. Replace , with space if its between ~.

How do i achieve this without using regular expressions in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a one-liner, and some stuff may seem redudant, but it's quite plain and understadable.

```
result = []
opened = False
for i, c in enumerate(data):
    if c == '~' and not opened:
        start = i
        opened = True
    elif c == '~' and opened:
        end = i + 1
        result.append(data[start:end].replace(' , ', ' '))
        opened = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice, readable code:

```py
def split_by_ap(word):

    i = iter(word.split('~'))

    result = []

    while True:
        space = next(i, None)
        word = next(i, None)

        if not word: break

        result.append(word.replace(',', ''))

    return result


print(split_by_ap("~ddd , eee~, ~aaaa~"))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `str.split` with `str.replace`:

```
data = "~ddd , eee~, ~aaaa~"
r = [(i+'~' if i[-1] != '~' else i).replace(', ', '') for i in data.split('~, ')]
```

Output:

```
['~ddd eee~', '~aaaa~']
```

Comment: Hi... How do you do this if the data is................. data = "~ddd , eee~, ~aaaa~"